# Simplifying PHP for further use

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am totally new to PHP and mySQL. I have pulled this data from mySQL database for a wordpress website but I would like to simplify my code so that it's more flexible so that I could customize my tables more easily. Any suggestion on where to start and also is there a standard way to do this ?

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$result1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title, post_date, guid, post_type FROM wp_posts");
$result2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name, term_id FROM wp_terms");
$result3 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT object_id, term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationships");

echo "<style>";
echo "body {font-family: Arial;}";

echo ".table_container { padding: 10px 12px 0px 12px;  border: 1px solid #ccc;  }";
echo ".table_container th { background-color:white; color:black; font-weight:bold; border-left: 1px solid white;}";
echo "</style></head>";
echo "<body>";

echo "<div class=\"table_container\"><table>";
echo "<tr><th style=\"padding-left:10px;\">Yvirskrift</th><th>Dato</th><th>Talari</th><th>Lurta</th></tr>";

foreach ($result1 as $row1) {
  if ($row1->post_type == "podcast") {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> $row1->post_title </td>";
    $date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row1->post_date));
    echo "<td> $date </td>";
    foreach ($result3 as $row3) {
      if ($row1->ID == $row3->object_id) {
        foreach ($result2 as $row2) {
          if($row3->term_taxonomy_id == $row2->term_id){
            echo "<td> $row2->name </td>";
            
          }
        }
      }
    }  
    $listen = "<a href=$row1->guid>Lurta her</a>";
    echo "<td> $listen </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
}  
echo "</table></div>";
?>
```

Comment: Tip: Separate your view code, use some kind of template to make this easier. WordPress isn't the most modern platform, so for making bigger, more complex applications look at other frameworks that make this a lot easier, like [Laravel](https://laravel.com).

Comment: even when you join the query,. you have to run every row and check if the data column has changed, that wouldm make it simewhat easier because you have lesser number of row to go through